# Embedded Python Block - Get value from work

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

How can I get a value calculated in def work(self, input_items, output_items) and use it in a getter method?
Until now, I defined a self.value but it does not change.
I attached a capture containing my code.[how to pass a to getA?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVWja.png)

Comment: posting the code inside your answer would help others help you

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want to do.
Could you name each variable and explain what you want to go where?

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. The objective is to access "a" from work() and use it in  getA(). I have tried before your answer the method you proposed but the result was 0 not 100. I think work has local effect, not global.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the way gnuradio blocks are run. I'm unfamiliar with them, but I peeked at their documentation. It could be that this sort of thing is impossible in gnuradio. But I don't really know that area, maybe take a step back and think about what you are trying to accomplish, it might be possible by sending more output parameters?

Comment: I thought about that, but I will search a little bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the value of `a` in `self.b`. 
So you can just return that value:

```
def getA(self):
  return self.b
```

Comment: It will not be OK. self.b does not change in work(). I need something to do this change.

Comment: @FriedrichMaar GNU Radio maintainer here. It does change. If it doesn't, something else is wrong. In this case, you're returning some `a` (which you didn't define anywhere in that scope, so you should be getting an exception); you should be, as m1sk recommends, returning `self.b`.